# GUI accessing a JSlider from another class

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jslider

I am adding a heater JButton and a heater JSlider to each Tab that I am creating, the heater JButton to turn it off and on and the heater JSlider to choose the temp.

The JSlider status is preset to false, so when I click the heater JButton to turn the heater on,

I need it to set the status of the JSlider to TRUE, how can I access the heater JSlider in the HEATER BUTTON class? and if not what other way is there to do this??.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class MasterGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

public MasterGUI(){

}

public void DisplayFrame(){
    ArrayList<Rooms> rooms;
    rooms = Building.getRoomList();

    JFrame master = new JFrame("Solar Master Control Panel"); 
    master.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Container content = master.getContentPane();
    content.setBackground(Color.lightGray);

    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
    JPanel tmpPanel;

    for(int x = 0; x < rooms.size(); x++){
        tmpPanel = new JPanel();
        String roomName = rooms.get(x).getName();
        int roomId = rooms.get(x).getId();
        tabbedPane.addTab(roomName + " Room " + roomId, tmpPanel);

        for(int i = 0; i < rooms.get(x).roomLights.size(); i++){
            int lightId = rooms.get(x).roomLights.get(i).getId();
            JButton lights = new JButton("Light" + lightId);
            lights.setBackground(Color.red);
            lights.addActionListener(new LightButton(roomId, lightId));
            ((JPanel) tabbedPane.getComponentAt(x)).add(lights);
        }

        JButton heater = new JButton("Heater");
        heater.setBackground(Color.red);
        heater.addActionListener(new HeaterButton(roomId));
        JSlider heaterSlider = new JSlider(68, 73);
        heaterSlider.setPaintTicks(true);
        heaterSlider.setPaintLabels(true);
        heaterSlider.setMajorTickSpacing(1);
        heaterSlider.addChangeListener(new HeaterSlider(roomId));
        heaterSlider.setEnabled(false);
        ((JPanel) tabbedPane.getComponentAt(x)).add(heater);
        ((JPanel) tabbedPane.getComponentAt(x)).add(heaterSlider);
    }
    master.add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    master.setSize(800, 600);
    content.add(tabbedPane);
    master.setVisible(true);
}
```

HEATERBUTTON CLASS

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.awt.*;
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;

public class HeaterButton implements ActionListener{
int roomNumber;

public HeaterButton(int room){
roomNumber = room;
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
ArrayList<Rooms> rooms;
rooms = Building.getRoomList();

    if(rooms.get(roomNumber - 1).roomHeater.getHeaterStatus() == true){
        rooms.get(roomNumber - 1).roomHeater.setHeaterOff();
        ((JButton)e.getSource()).setBackground(Color.red);

    }else{
        rooms.get(roomNumber - 1).roomHeater.setHeaterOn();
        ((JButton)e.getSource()).setBackground(Color.green);

    }
}
}
```

Comment: You should look into the command pattern (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern). the HeaterButton class is kind of confusing because its no button. Swing has an Action class wich u can use as an interface instead of the ActionListener. This way you can just give the button a certain action to execute :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the slider first and then pass it to the button.

Change:

```
 heater.addActionListener(new HeaterButton(roomId));
```

To:

```
 heater.addActionListener(new HeaterButton(roomId, slider));
```